# how to get value of number into alphabet in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How to I get value of number like 1,2,3,4............ in alphabet?

Is there any function which convert it directly?

i have a blanck table  with column emp_id,EMPfname,emplname,doj

now i want to create 50000 employe with cursor..how can i do?

Comment: To alphabet means 1 as one,2 as two ..... ?

Comment: Use: **DECLARE @number INT = 1; `SELECT  Letter = CHAR(64 + @number);`** **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/2408/0)**

Comment: @lad2025 Why you haven't put that as an answer?

Comment: @AnupAgrawal This has to be quick demo, but know there is the same answer, so I will leave it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
DECLARE @num INT = 1; 
SELECT
   Letters = Char(64 + @num)
```